# Looping over only a certain range of object indices in python

Tags: pandas, loops, object, indexing, append

I am trying to append a pandas dataframe based on two pre-existing columns in that dataframe.  The issue I'm having is that the index of the pandas dataframe is in object format, not integer format.  To make things more complicated, I only want to append a certain range of the dataframe, leaving the remaining cells in the new column as 'NaN'.  In order to append over only a certain range of the dataframe, I will have to use a "for" loop.

Here is my question:  How do I loop over a certain range of the dataframe when I have an object index?

My initial pandas dataframe is simply...

```
import pandas as pd

dates = ['2005Q4','2006Q1','2006Q2','2006Q3','2006Q4','2007Q1','2007Q2']
col1 = [ 5.9805, 6.2181, 6.3508, 6.7878, 6.6212, 6.4583, 6.4068 ]
col2 = [ 'NaN', -0.001054985938, -0.121731711952, 0.046275331889, 
         -0.017517211963, -0.023422842422, 0.009072170884 ]

data = pd.DataFrame(
                    {
                     'col1':   col1,
                     'col2':   col2
                     },
                     columns = [
                                'col1',
                                'col2'
                                ],
                     index = dates
                    )
```

All I'm trying to do is something like this...

```
data['col3'] = 'NaN'

for i in range('2006Q1','2006Q4',1):
    data['col3'][i]  =  data['col1'][i-1] +\
                        data['col2'][i]
```

Naively, I had hoped that python would be able to correlate the object name in the index with the actual index number associated with that particular indice.  For example, if I define the index as given, python would be able to know that '2005Q4' is index = 0, '2006Q1' is index = 1, etc.  In this way, I could use object strings in the range() function and it would still know the integer I'm referring to.  However, this appears not to be the case.

I need to avoid converting the objects into date format as well.  It is important that I keep the index in the format 'YearQuarter', and I have yet to find a simple way of using pd.to_datetime that is able to do this.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to loop over only a certain range of object-based indices in python?

Answer (score 0):

Using `.index()` with a list returns the index of the item you're looking for. Try this tweak to your `for` loop.

```
for i in range(dates.index('2006Q1'),dates.index('2006Q4'),1):
```

Obviously however much more efficient ways to do this. `.shift()` shifts your entire column up or down however much you want :

```
data['col3'] = data.col1 - data.col2.shift(-1)
```